# Bergen and Voss by bike in the end of March

Tags: weather-and-climate, bicycles, norway, bergen

I have a few days off to work at the end of March and I would visit Bergen and Voss.

Someone know if is possible rent bike also in this period? ( usually rent a bike and cycling season starts in April ).

It's snow in late March or its a bit hot than january?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there's probably a lot of snow in late March!

The first screenshot below shows the height profile of the Bergen - Voss bike ride. As you can see, the highest point is 464 m.a.s.l at Kvamskogen. The second screenshot shows the weather and snow depth in 2015 at Kvamskogen. In late March 2015 there was approximately 150 cm of snow.

There's a fair chance the road is free from snow, but the normal temperature is 0 degrees, and it rains/snows a lot, so it's 50/50.

The bike ride is 170 km and hilly, and the weather can be quite harsh. I strongly recommend you to not take this trip in late March, unless you're **very well trained and prepared** for *many hours* in cold windy and wet conditions.

It's a **very nice** ride in the summer time, so I highly recommend you try to do the trip another time!

[image]

[image]